# How can I implement a custom Flutter slider that gradually increases it's track thickness?

Tags: flutter, dart, uislider, flutter-custompainter

##### Context

I'm working on a custom slider widget in Flutter where I need the slider track to change its thickness slightly in an increasing way. I have not found any built-in properties in the [`Slider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) widget that could help achieve this effect. The thickness should increase as it gets closer to the end and decrease as it moves towards the start.

##### What I tried

I tried to create a *custom* [`SliderTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData-class.html) and change the [`trackShape`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData/trackShape.html), here's the relevant code:

```dart
class CustomSliderTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  final double overlayWidth;

  const CustomSliderTrackShape({
    this.overlayWidth = 30.0,
  });

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final double overlayRadius = overlayWidth / 2;

    final double trackLeft = offset.dx + overlayRadius;
    final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height / 2);
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight!;

    // --> not sure how to increase the width of the track

    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width - (2 * overlayRadius) + 10;

    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}
```

And it's usage:

```dart
SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        // --> Using it here.
        trackShape: CustomSliderTrackShape(),
      ),
      child: Slider(
        value: 0.4,
        onChanged: (newValue) {},
      ),
    )
```

which results in (seems like the regular `Slider`):

[image]

However, the **desired output** is:

[image]

##### Question

How can I modify the `getPreferredRect` function to create a custom slider that increases its height/thickness as it comes to the end? should I be using [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) instead in order to achieve a slider with varying track thickness?

---

Here's the code as a fully runnable snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Custom Slider Example')),
        body: MySlider(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySliderState createState() => _MySliderState();
}

class _MySliderState extends State<MySlider> {
  double _value = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        trackHeight: 6,
        
        trackShape: CustomSliderTrackShape(),
      ),
      child: Slider(
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        divisions: 100,
        value: _value,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSliderTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  final double overlayWidth;

  const CustomSliderTrackShape({
    this.overlayWidth = 30.0,
  });

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final double overlayRadius = overlayWidth / 2;

    final double trackLeft = offset.dx + overlayRadius;
    final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height / 2);
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight!;

    // --> not sure how to increase the width of the track

    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width - (2 * overlayRadius) + 10;

    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}
```

Comment: `The SliderTrackShape.getPreferredRect method is used to map slider-relative gesture coordinates to the correct thumb position on the track. It is also used to horizontally position tick marks, when the slider is discrete.` You will want to override the `paint` method to paint your custom shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with `Paint`, hope this help. Also try to find better ratio for your case,

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=756adbd5456b8c59c74a8a2650feeb26)

```dart
class CustomSliderTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    Offset? secondaryOffset,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 2,
  }) {
    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );

    final radius = trackRect.height * .3; //todo: use your trackHeightRatio
    final thumbWidth =
        sliderTheme.thumbShape!.getPreferredSize(isEnabled, isDiscrete).width;

    final Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(
          radius + trackRect.left, trackRect.top + trackRect.height / 2) //lt
      ..lineTo(trackRect.width + thumbWidth, trackRect.top) //rt
      ..arcToPoint(
        //rb
        Offset(trackRect.width + thumbWidth, trackRect.bottom),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
      )
      ..lineTo(trackRect.left, trackRect.bottom - radius) //lb
      ..arcToPoint(
        //lt
        Offset(trackRect.left, trackRect.top + trackRect.height / 2),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
      )
      ..close();

    final Paint trackPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.grey.shade300;
    context.canvas.drawPath(path, trackPaint);
  }
}
```

[image]